# How to partition $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

We note that  we can partition the set of integers  $\mathbb Z $ into the set of odd integers and even integers, specifically, we have $$\mathbb Z = 2\mathbb Z \cup (2\mathbb Z +1),$$ where
$2\mathbb Z = \{ 2n: n\in \mathbb Z \}$ and $2\mathbb Z +1 = \{ 2n+1: n\in \mathbb Z \}.$  Let's put this fact in other words,  we  can write $\mathbb Z $ as a union of two sets, let's say $A=\{ 2n: n\in \mathbb Z \}$ and $B=\{ 2n+1: n\in \mathbb Z \},$ with parameter is running through
$\mathbb Z.$

I'm curious to know how this fact goes in higher dimensions, in other words, what happens if we replace $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ in above observations?

> Can we write $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ as union of two sets (or more sets) and  each sets the parameter is running through $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$?

Side note: (1)  Roughly speaking this kind of trick is useful to partition the series in higher dimension in many situations.
(2)$\mathbb  Z \times \mathbb Z = (A\cup B) \times (A\cup B).$

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is numerable, there is a bijection with $\mathbb{Z}$, and then you can pull back the "partition" in odd and even numbers. If you instead want a partition in 4 pieces, you can partition on odd$\times$odd, odd$\times$even, even$\times$odd and even$\times$even.

Comment: Shouldn't the sets be called just $A$ and $B$? $A_n$ doesn't make any sense to me: what would $A_1$ be? And $A_4$?

Comment: Of course, we could take
$$
\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z= (2\Bbb Z) \times \Bbb Z \cup (2\Bbb Z + 1) \times \Bbb Z
$$

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum: Thanks. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks. But the question is for $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z.$

Comment: You could split $\mathbb Z^2$ into two sets by whether $m+n$ is even or odd for $(m, n) \in \mathbb Z^2.$

Comment: Elaborating on md2perpe's comment, let $A=\{(n,2m+n)\mid m,n\in \mathbb Z\}$ and let $B=\{(n,2m+1+n)\mid m,n\in \mathbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The natural partitions of $\mathbb Z^n$ along this line are given by the cosets of a subgroup of finite index, that is, a subgroup generated by $n$ linearly independent vectors.

The number of classes is exactly the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix whose columns are the coordinate of the generators.

For example, take $v_1=(1,2)$ and $v_2=(4,1)$. Then the subgroup $H=\mathbb Z v_1 + \mathbb Z v_2$ has index $7$, which corresponds to the seven lattice points inside the parallelogram defined by $0, v_1, v_2, v_1+v_2$.
If these points are $p_1, \dots, p_7$, then $\mathbb Z^2 = (p_1 + H) \cup \cdots \cup (p_7 + H)$.

[image]

Comment: @1hf: Thanks. Can you explain bit more?